# Webpack error ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (prop) [./~/connect-mongo/src/index.js:10,0]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to prepare my Express/ReactJS app for production with webpack, and when running `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js`

I get error:

> ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (prop) [./~/connect-mongo/src/index.js:10,0]

Here's my `webpack.production.config` file:

```
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './server.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel'},
      { test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel'},
      { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel'}
    ],
  },
  node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      module: 'empty'
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**EDIT**:

The error is a result of line 10 in node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index:

```
'use strict';
/* eslint indent: [error, 4] */

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb');

function defaultSerializeFunction(session) {
    // Copy each property of the session to a new object
    const obj = {};
    let prop;

    for (prop in session) {
        if (prop === 'cookie') {
            // Convert the cookie instance to an object, if possible
            // This gets rid of the duplicate object under session.cookie.data property
            obj.cookie = session.cookie.toJSON ? session.cookie.toJSON() : session.cookie;
        } else {
            obj[prop] = session[prop];
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: How about the source that causes the error?

Comment: Thanks, updated with the referenced line

Comment: Are you using Babel? if so, are you using babel-plugin-uglify?

Comment: Yes, I am using Babel, but not babel-plugin-uglify

Comment: Are you uglifying the ES6 source or the Babelified ES5 source? If you're Babeling the ES6 you'll need babel-plugin-uglify.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, my .babelrc is as follows, if that helps: {
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}

Comment: I installed babel-plugin-uglify and I now get this error: Module build failed: Error: The (uglify) Babel 5 plugin is being run with Babel 6.

Comment: Oh, ok. Not sure--I think we're running uglification on the transpiled code, so we're not using a plugin ourselves.

Comment: I've gotten it to work by removing exclude: /node_modules/. My bundle.js is 2.8mb though, I'm not sure if that has something to do with it...

Comment: Nope, size isn't relevant-you probably have a dependency that isn't bundled for ES5.

Comment: Although I've gotten no errors from webpack, now I'm getting errors related to dependencies in the browser...dependencies that are only used server-side. Should webpack be bundling these into bundle.js?