# ng serve --prod for ng-cli results in UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, babeljs, angular-cli, uglifyjs

I am using the [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) (ng-cli) for my project. When I type in `ng serve`, the application runs. However, when I type in `ng serve --prod`, I get the following error.

```
ERROR in vendor.bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (IdUtil) [./~/my-lib/dist/src/common/util.js:7,0][vendor.bundle.js:9318,6]
```

It is [a known issue that UglifyJs cannot parse ES6](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2972).

Furthermore, these SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410888/webpack-error-error-in-bundle-js-from-uglifyjs-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-na) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387544/angular-2-webpack-build-from-uglifyjs-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc)), suggest changing `tsconfig.json` to target `es5`. What I am unclear of is whether they mean the `tsconfig.json` of the consuming Angular project or the one that was used to generate the library. At any rate, my Angular project's `tsconfig.json` already targets `es5`. It looks like the following.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` of the library that was imported into the Angular project looks like the following and does NOT target `es5` but `es6`. By the way, I cannot simply flip the switch in this library from `es6` back to `es5` (I just tried) as I am using `es6` classes like `Set` and `Map` (the use of these classes is so severe that changing them would not be trivial, to say the least; had I known about all of this, I would have opted to avoid es6 feature altogether).

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "diagnostics": false,
        "listEmittedFiles": false,
        "listFiles": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

Here are my questions.

- How can I disable uglification with Angular-CLI when using `ng serve --prod`?
- Is the problem with the `es5/es6` target of my Angular project or the imported library?
- The SO posts seem to suggest that I can pre-process the imported library through babel (which I've never used before) before Angular-CLI does its magic via UglifyJs for `ng serve --prod`. Is this procedure documented? If so, please let me know how to do this. The `angular-cli.json` is where I understand ng-cli is configured from. I can't make heads or tails how to hook in the babel pre-processing, if this suggestion is true.

Comment: FYI, my workaround was to compile my external library from TS -> ES6 -> (babel) -> ES5. That was the only way for me right now.

Comment: Transpiling ES6 to ES5 increases the build times dramatically, see my answer below. Hope it helps...

Comment: @JaneWayne how did you add in the (babel) step?

Answer (score 3):

There're a few tricks you can use to handle ES6/ES2015 minification.

You can use [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) by bebraw - which decouples UglifyJs from webpack. Usage is as follows:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {...},
    output: {...},
    module: {...},
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin()
    ]
};
```

And then, you have to replace `uglify-js` reference in your **package.json** with the following:

`"uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony",`

Comment: great, this fix the problem!

Comment: This solution is not going to work easily in an angular-cli environment, in which the webpack configuration happens behind the curtains.

Comment: actually cli is the most practical way to work with, but i'm afraid you have to switch to manually providing the build configs :(

Comment: the last line goes into package.json

Answer (score 1):

ng serve command is especially designed to work in a development environment.

try to run:

```
ng build --prod
```

if you testing your app with IE:

run the command

```
npm install -dev angular2-ie9-shims
```

and than you have to add in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/angular2-ie9-shims/shims_for_IE@2.1.2.js",
    "../node_modules/angular2-ie9-shims/shims_for_IE@2.0.0-beta.17.js",
    "../node_modules/angular2-ie9-shims/shims_for_IE.dev.js"
  ],
```

or just add the in index.html

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/66df335998d097fa8fe46dec41f1183737332021/shims_for_IE.js" type="text/plain"></script>
```

Comment: I'm actually on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was with a NPM module called Autotrack from Google.  The package is in ES6, and it's a .js file so Typescript did not transpile it.  I had to manually include an ES5 version of Autotrack in order for uglify to work.

Comment: I discovered it was Autotrack by searching through the vendor.js file in the dist folder for the variable name that uglify was complaining about.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you included them?

Comment: I downloaded the ES5 source from GitHub and manually referenced the .js file in the script tag - Then removed the Autotrack reference from the package.json

Comment: For me I solved it by just using import 'autotrack/autotrack.js';.. this will add all plugins but the filesize difference on build was just 0.02kb.. and I can live with that :P